# Makefile produces undefined references

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am getting the following errors:

```
//usr/local/lib/libsmfitting.so: undefined reference to `VO_FaceParts::VO_GetOneFacePart(unsigned int) const'
//usr/local/lib/libsmfitting.so: undefined reference to `cv::estimateRigidTransform(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Being produced from this makefile:

```
Cxx=g++
CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/local/include/vosm/smfitting -I/usr/local/include/vosm/smbuilding -I/usr/local/include/vosm/comalgs -I/usr/local/include/vosm/cvcommon -I/usr/local/include/vosm/ensembletraining -I/usr/local/include/vosm/featureextraction -I/usr/local/include/vosm/integraltransform -I/usr/local/include/vosm/utils
LIBS = -lopencv_ml -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_objdetect -lcomalgs -lcvcommon -lensembletraining -lfeatureextraction -lintegraltransform -lsmbuilding -lutils -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lsmfitting

all: faceApp.cpp
    $(Cxx) -o faceApp faceApp.cpp $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

The code appears to be correct and the libraries appear to be built correctly, I believe the error lies in the makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the libraries when linking is significant, and should be in reverse dependency order. So if library B depends on library A, then you need to put B before A when linking.

In your case it seems that the `smfitting` library depends on one of the OpenCV libraries, as well as some other library, so you need to put it before those libraries.

Comment: thanks that solved everything! Is there a way to build the libs so they don't need that type of dependency resolution?